# how to delim by double quotes in a for in batch scripting

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, delimiter

I have a file and I wish to use the for command to go through it. My issue is that I try to delim by double quotes character ["] and I have to escape it, so my for would look like this:

```
for /f tokens^=1^,2^,3^ delims^=^<^"^= %%a in ("%%i") do (

)
```

And I don't understand why is it that if I remove the last [^] from `tokens tokens^=1^,2^,3**^**` I get an error: that delims was unexpected.

Any suggestions on how can I delim by double quotes and not have to escape every other character?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is, that you use the options without enclosing quotes,
like in
`FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=[]" ...`.

But if you want to use a quote as a delim character, you can't use the enclosing quotes anymore.
And then nearly all characters must be escaped with a caret, as `,=;<space>` are also standard token delimiters.

Even the spaces have to be escaped to create a single option token.
`for /f tokens^=1^,2^,3 delims^=^<^"^= %%a`
will be split into 
`for` - `/f` - `tokens=1,2,3` - `delims=<"=`

But the `/F` expects exactly one or none option token.

Comment: @jeb You can make life a bit easier, `for /f tokens^=1-3delims^=^<^"^= %a` will do also. The hyphen doesn't need to be escaped for a range of `tokens^=1-3` and the space between the options isn't necessary.